# Is there any research about effect of unfamiliar environment on stress?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, psychology, stress

It seems intuitive to me that there is some kind of stress when one is put in an unfamiliar place (There's probably effect on cognitive abilities too). However, I can't find any paper in psychology which discusses that potential relationship.

Comment: How would you measure the familiarity of an environment?

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following

[Older people's cardiac responses as indicators of stress in familiar and unfamiliar environments (Lewis & Phillips, 2012)](https://doi.org/10.1002/dev.420220608)

I also found:

Padilla, A. M., Alvarez, M., & Lindholm, K. J. (1986). Generational status and personality factors as predictors of stress in students. *Hispanic Journal of Behavioral Sciences*, 8(3), 275-288.
DOI: [10.1002/dev.420220608](https://doi.org/10.1002/dev.420220608)

> stressful events center on loss of familial and cultural ties as well as on relative discomfort in an unfamiliar social environment

### References

Lewis M. J. & Phillips J. E. (2012). Older people's cardiac responses as indicators of stress in familiar and unfamiliar environments. *Psychophysiology*, 49(4): pp. 478-483
DOI: [10.1111/j.1469-8986.2011.01321.x](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-8986.2011.01321.x) PMID: [22176515](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22176515)

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in related research on how unfamiliar environments negatively affect sleep quality.

[Tamaki, M., Bang, J. W., Watanabe, T., & Sasaki, Y. (2016). Night watch in one brain hemisphere during sleep associated with the first-night effect in humans. Current biology, 26(9), 1190-1194.](https://www.cell.com/current-biology/fulltext/S0960-9822(16)30174-9)

This research has also received substantial popular press coverage, for example from [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2016/04/21/health/poor-sleep-while-traveling/index.html) and [NPR](https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2016/04/21/474691141/half-your-brain-stands-guard-when-sleeping-in-a-new-place).